# ArcMap not allowing attributes of layer to be edited?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, arcgis-10.5

In ArcMap, I am trying to remove some statistical areas manually from a layer of statistical areas. To this end, I am using the Editor Toolbar. But when I try to choose which layer to edit, it won't let me click "ok". What may be causing this? Is there a more simple way to proceed?

The following screenshot is what I see when I try to allow editing of the statistical areas layer. The "ok" button does not turn black (i.e. is not clickable) no matter which layer I choose.

[image]

Comment: Do you have rights to edit that feature service? You can't edit a CSV layer within ArcMap.

Comment: It is not the csv that I want to edit. Rather it is the .lyr file called statistical_areas_2011

Comment: Layer files do not contain data. They just point at the actual data source. In order to edit data, the data format must be editable by ArcGIS, the license level of ArcGIS must support editing of that format, and you must have read-write access to the data source. I much prefer to use the layer context menu to choose the source for editing.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Vince (in response to you commenting that `"It is not the csv that I want to edit. Rather it is the .lyr file called statistical_areas_2011"`):

> Layer files do not contain data. They just point at the actual data
>   source. In order to edit data, the data format must be editable by
>   ArcGIS, the license level of ArcGIS must support editing of that
>   format, and you must have read-write access to the data source. I much
>   prefer to use the layer context menu to choose the source for editing.